# Why Rails i18n doesn't look up under activerecord.attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-i18n

Versions:

```
2.3.4 :011 > RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.3.4" 

2.3.4 :012 > Rails::VERSION::STRING
=> "4.1.8"
```

Backends:

```
2.3.4 :013 > I18n.backend
 => #<I18n::Backend::Simple:0x007fa2d84eb560 @initialized=false, @translations=nil>
```

Gems installed:

```
$ gem list | grep -i i18n
i18n (0.9.3, 0.9.1, 0.7.0)
i18n-debug (1.1.0)
i18n-tasks (0.9.20)
i18n_yaml_sorter (0.2.0)
rails-i18n (4.0.9)
```

Content of the yml:

```
---
en:
  attributes:
    patient:
        id: "1234"
```

Rails console output:

```
2.3.4 :014 > Patient.human_attribute_name(:id)
[i18n-debug] en.activerecord.attributes.patient.id => "1234"
 => "1234" 

2.3.4 :015 > I18n.t('patient.id')
[i18n-debug] en.patient.id => nil
 => "translation missing: en.patient.id"
```

Question:

> Why i18n looks up regular path "en.patient.id" but does not fall back
>   to "en.activerecord.attributes.patient.id"?

Comment: There is no helper that will automatically fall back to using the ActiveRecord scope. You could call I18n.t('attributes.patient.id') in this case if you needed.

Comment: Why do you think that asking explicitly for `I18n.t('patient.id')` should return the translation stored under `attributes.patient.id`. What documentation do you follow?

Comment: @spickermann, you were right. I have accurately check and noticed that I mistaken. Thank you.